# "gcc main.cpp -lcjson -lm" is ok,but "g++ main.cpp -lcjson -lm" is error

Tags: linux, g++

I'm compiling an example with `libcjson`.
`gcc main.cpp  -lcjson -lm` works OK, but
`g++ main.cpp  -lcjson -lm` gives this error.

```
/usr/local/lib/libcjson.so: undefined reference to `pow'
/usr/local/lib/libcjson.so: undefined reference to `floor'
```

Why is that?

Comment: `libcjson.so` could have been built incorrectly. What's the output of `ldd /usr/local/lib/libcjson.so`?

Comment: What is the OS, and what is the compiler version? And maybe, what standard library are you using? I believe I've seen MinGW do similar, but thy seem to have broken headers. I've also seen Newlib do some unusual things.